# Regex not working with python

Tags: python, regex

Hey guys I am new to python regex. Since I am bad in regex  i never spend more time in regex but i have a project now and i face some problems in my project.

When I run following piece of code

```
import re
line = "100, 1000 or 10000?";
num = re.sub(r'{3,4}', "", line)
print num
```

I get error like

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Since am new to regex i don't know why am getting this. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What do you expect to be the output?
The error comes from the fact that you told the regex to match something 3 to 4 times, but not what

Answer (score 3):

`{3,4}` is a modifier; there needs to be something to modify. It basically means "from three to four of". What does "from three to four of" even mean?

`\d` is "a digit". `\d{3,4}` means "from three to four of a digit" (i.e. 3-4 digits).